# R combine data frame columns with regex

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(
    c = c(1 , 2) , a1 = c(1 , 2) , a2 = c(3 , 4) , b1 = c(5 , 6) , b2 = c(7 , 8)
)
  c a1 a2 b1 b2
1 1  1  3  5  7
2 2  2  4  6  8
```

That I would like to merged columns based on shared prefixes to become this data frame:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(
    c = c(1 , 2 , 1 , 2) , a = c(1 , 2 , 3 , 4) , b = c(5 , 6 , 7 , 8)
)
  c a b
1 1 1 5
2 2 2 6
3 1 3 7
4 2 4 8
```

The only way I can think of is to try do this using `melt()`. This was my attempt:

```
﻿﻿melt(dat , measure.vars = c(grep("^a" , colnames(dat)) , grep("^b" , colnames(dat))))
    variable value
1 1       a1     1
2 2       a1     2
3 1       a2     3
4 2       a2     4
5 1       b1     5
6 2       b1     6
7 1       b2     7
8 2       b2     8
>
```

Needless to say, this is incorrect.

Comment: I think `melt` was an excellent start. Now you just need to read the help page for `?dcast` and complete the process.

Comment: Two things: using `dcast(data = dat , formula = value ~ variable)
` will get me back to where I was (In theory, I think, though it's throwing an error saying it can't find `value` for some reason, but also, I can't seem to figure out how to strip the numbers off of the `variable`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `melt` from `data.table` which takes multiple `patterns` in the `measure`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(dat), measure=patterns("^a\\d+", "^b\\d+"), 
                   value.name=c("a", "b"))[, variable:= NULL][]
#   c a b
#1: 1 1 5
#2: 2 2 6
#3: 1 3 7
#4: 2 4 8
```

Comment: This was the first one I was able to adapt to my specific dataset. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is a case where base R's `reshape` is actually perfectly suited.

```
reshape(dat, idvar="c", direction="long", sep="", varying=-1, timevar=NULL)

#    c a b
#1.1 1 1 5
#2.1 2 2 6
#1.2 1 3 7
#2.2 2 4 8
```

The `sep=""` essentially tells `reshape()` there is nothing between the group identifier (`a` and `b` in this case) and the `time` indicator - (`1` and `2` in this case) in your variable names. So all the renaming is taken care of automagically.

It might be more obvious if I don't set the `timevar=NULL` as well:

```
reshape(dat, idvar="c", direction="long", sep="", varying=-1)

#    c time a b
#1.1 1    1 1 5
#2.1 2    1 2 6
#1.2 1    2 3 7
#2.2 2    2 4 8
```

If you have many id variables that you wish to keep constant for your other melted data, then try this code:

```
# an example bit of data
dat2 <- cbind(x=1:2,y=2:3,z=3:4, dat)
dat2

#  x y z c a1 a2 b1 b2
#1 1 2 3 1  1  3  5  7
#2 2 3 4 2  2  4  6  8

idv <- match(c("x","y","z","c"), names(dat2))
reshape(dat2, idvar=idv, direction="long", sep="", varying=-idv, timevar=NULL)

#          x y z c a b
#1.2.3.1.1 1 2 3 1 1 5
#2.3.4.2.1 2 3 4 2 2 6
#1.2.3.1.2 1 2 3 1 3 7
#2.3.4.2.2 2 3 4 2 4 8
```

Comment: I like this approach. I'm having trouble with `varying`. If my first 12 columns are to be excluded from reshaping (like `c`), I'm trying something like -(1:12), but this isn't working. Any insights? 

`data2 <- reshape(data1 , idvar = names(data1)[1:12] , direction = "long" , sep = "" , varying = -(1:12) , timevar = NULL)
`.

Comment: This is the best answer, imo.  Base R and no one in hell can figure out how to use `reshape()`. Nice work.

Comment: @RichardScriven - I am one with `reshape()` - it speaks to me. :-P

Comment: @mnosefish - see my updated answer which shows how to exclude other columns. You essentially had it already.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  gather(key, value, -c) %>% # this gets you were you were...
  separate(key, into = c("letter", "number"), sep = 1) %>%
  spread(letter, value) %>%
  select(-number)
```

Comment: I'm thoroughly unfamiliar with tidyr until today. WIll this work with multiple columns like c which will not be merged?